# Left alignment of chapter titles in the table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents, vertical-alignment

I have added some commands in order to have the title of each chapter centered, but this also modifies the table of contents! 
I wanted to keep at the beginning of the chapter, the title in central position, but for the table of contents I want a left alignment.

This is my preambol:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,twoside]{book}

\usepackage[paper = letterpaper, centering,
            lmargin = 1.5in, rmargin = 1.5in,
            tmargin = 1.5in, bmargin = 1.5in]{geometry}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{#1}}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\thepage}
\fancyhead[LO]{\itshape\nouppercase{\rightmark}}
\fancyhead[RE]{\itshape\nouppercase{\leftmark}}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,positioning}

\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{mwe}    % loads »blindtext« and »graphicx«
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{braket}

\usepackage{charter} 
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]% NEW
    {\fontfamily{ptm}\Large\bfseries\centering}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{20pt}{\huge}% NEW
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{30pt}{20pt}% NEW

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows}
\usepackage{cool}
\Style{DSymb={\mathrm d},DShorten=true,IntegrateDifferentialDSymb=\mathrm{d}}
\newtheorem{definizione}{Definizione}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{mydef}{Definition}

\makeatletter
\def\cleardoublepage{\clearpage\if@twoside \ifodd\c@page\else
  \hbox{}\thispagestyle{empty}\newpage\if@twocolumn\hbox{}\newpage\fi\fi\fi}
\makeatother
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: A Warm Welcome to TeX.SE! Please post a full MWE http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3343/what-makes-a-good-mwe

Comment: Adding some code produces a normal result… Try to post a minimal example illustrating the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution. New command `\chapalign` with `\newcommand{\chapalign}{\centering}` is used

```
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]% NEW
    {\fontfamily{ptm}\Large\bfseries\chapalign}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{20pt}{\huge}% NEW
```

This command is redefined localy before table of contents

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,twoside]{book}
\usepackage{mwe}


\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]% NEW
    {\fontfamily{ptm}\Large\bfseries\chapalign}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{20pt}{\huge}% NEW
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{30pt}{20pt}% NEW


\newcommand{\chapalign}{\centering}


\begin{document}
{\renewcommand{\chapalign}{}
\tableofcontents}
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```